# Return an integer if nothing is found (TSQL ASP.NET VB)

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, t-sql

I need to return a value (0) if nothing is found in an SQL call.

Here is what i have (edited/simplified to make more sense out of context), this is baing called from the codebehind.

```
sql1 = "INSERT INTO [Xtr_MenuItems]([menu_order]) 
values(1 + (select max(menu_order) from [Xtr_MenuItems]))
```

SO into database i insert the max number found in [menu_order] + 1. this works fine, assuming something is found.

However, if `(select max(menu_order) from [Xtr_MenuItems]))` fails (nothing found) then i want to return 0 (as 1 + nothing = nothing, and sql explodes)

How can i do this? I have tried 'IF EXISTS', 'OUTPUT' in various ways but cant get it to work...

Comment: Why do you need to add 1?  Are you trying to get an incrementing integer as a Primary Key?  If so, then just set that column to be the ID and you never need to insert anything into it.  Just set IsIdentity to Yes and Identity Increment to 1 in the table's design.

Comment: @JonathonCowley - i need to insert 1 IF this is the first item in a sub-menu, the idea being i can then change the menu display order.

Comment: Gotcha.  In that case you want the ISNULL function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sql1 = "INSERT INTO [Xtr_MenuItems]([menu_order]) 
values(1 + ISNULL((select max(menu_order) from [Xtr_MenuItems]),0))
```

I used ISNULL function where if the result of query is null returns 0

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `values`, you could use `select` straight away:

```
insert  Xtr_MenuItems
        (menu_order) 
select  1 + isnull(max(menu_order),0) 
from    Xtr_MenuItems
```

Answer (score 0):

[COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) is the standards compliant way to provides alternatives for null values:

```
sql1 = "INSERT INTO [Xtr_MenuItems]([menu_order]) 
values(1 + COALESCE((select max(menu_order) from [Xtr_MenuItems]),0))
```

It has similar syntax to the [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function provided by Microsoft, but will work across multiple db platforms and can handle multiple fallbacks.

W3Schools privides a great introduction to null handling [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp).